# Closest distance + vertices of two meshes

Tags: graphics, cgal

I would like to find two vertices of two meshes (1 vertex per mesh) that define the closest distance between them. Or the two triangles would be fine I guess.

However I'm not sure how to search for this in CGAL's documentation, I'm sure that this is doable with some existing tool (probably based on a 3d distance field and/or AABBs). Could I please get a hint (keywords/link) on what to look for?

I've been pointed to the [Optimal Distances](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polytope_distance_d/group__PkgOptimalDistances.html) CGAL package, but it's not exactly what I want, since it outputs the distance and the coordinates, so finding the vertex ID is an additional computational overhead.

I've already implemented a collision detection with CGAL to find the triangle-triangle intersection in a triangle-soup, using AABB-trees. I guess that I should be somehow close to this, although now a simple soup with all me object-triangles wouldn't do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution found was this:

CGAL's [Optimal Distances](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polytope_distance_d/group__PkgOptimalDistances.html) package can give an approximation of the closest distance between the convex hulls of two meshes, without explicitly computing the hulls. As a result one gets the shortest distance between these hulls, and the coordinates of the 2 points that lie on them and define this distance.

Then these coordinates can be used as a search-query in kd-trees that contains the original vertices of the meshes in order to find the closest vertices.

In case one mesh is non-convex, the hull that CGAL is using is very approximate, so convex decomposition might be necessary. In such a case one would have to check distances for each convex part and then take the shortest distance.

The above would result in something like this:

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE0Gv.jpg)